# I need to know how can i call a value from other function

Tags: angular

I have 2 functions. I am fetching data from one function how can i call the data value from other function

Here is code example

```
export class IntroPage {

  fun1() {

  this.messageService.getGroupMessages(this.group_id).subscribe( (data:any) => {
  console.log(data);
  this.groupname = data.groupname; // As here need to show this.groupname in second function
  });

  }

  fun2() {

   console.log(this.groupname); // Need to show value here 

  }
}
```

I know i can pass value by function like `this.fun2(this.groupname);`  But i dont want to do like this. There is any way to show without passing it through the function or set it globally in file ?

Comment: How about calling `fun2()` inside `fun1()` when you got data?

Comment: why would you do that? the correct way to do this is directly in the `fun1()` or `this.fun2(data.groupname)`